# Pivot DataFrame with Multiple Dimensions

Tags: python, pivot-table

I have two reports, one with training status and then one master roster. The training report has 15 columns. The master roster has 9 columns. I have created a small sample below. My terminology might not be correct since I'm new to Python.

Training Report (I add the `Training` column with some conditional logic from the `Training Code` column. Please note, a name can be repeated if they have completed multiple training such as `Name2`.)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Name1','Name2','Name2','Name3'],
                   'Office':['A', 'B', 'B', 'A'],
                   'Position':['Director','Manager','Manager','Analyst'],
                   'Training Code':['C3','C1-L','C2','C1-B'],
                   'Training':['ADV','BEG','INT','BEG']
                  })
```

Output

```
    Name Office  Position Training Code Training
0  Name1      A  Director            C3      ADV
1  Name2      B   Manager          C1-L      BEG
2  Name2      B   Manager            C2      INT
3  Name3      A   Analyst          C1-B      BEG
```

Master Roster (I add the `Required` column based on the condition of the `Status` column. This is a unique list of names of everyone on the roster.)

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Name1','Name2','Name3','Name4'],
                   'Office':['A', 'B', 'A', 'C'],
                   'Position':['Director','Manager','Analyst','Supervisor'],
                   'Symbol':['OS','BP','OD','EO'],
                   'Status':[1,3,8,2],
                   'Required':['Required','Required','Recommended','Required']})
```

Output

```
    Name Office    Position Symbol  Status     Required
0  Name1      A    Director     OS       1     Required
1  Name2      B     Manager     BP       3     Required
2  Name3      A     Analyst     OD       8  Recommended
3  Name4      C  Supervisor     EO       2     Required
```

I need to merge the master roster and training data so it looks like below.

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Name1','Name2','Name3','Name4'],
                   'Office':['A', 'B', 'A', 'C'],
                   'Position':['Director','Manager','Analyst','Supervisor'],
                   'Symbol':['OS','BP','OD','EO'],
                   'Status':[1,3,8,2],
                   'Required':['Required','Required','Recommended','Required'],
                   'ADV':[1,0,0,0],
                   'INT':[0,1,0,0],
                   'BEG':[0,1,1,0]
                  })
```

DESIRED OUTPUT (Unique list of names and information about each name - the master roster, merged with a pivoted version of the training report.)

```
    Name Office    Position Symbol  Status     Required  ADV  INT  BEG
0  Name1      A    Director     OS       1     Required    1    0    0
1  Name2      B     Manager     BP       3     Required    0    1    1
2  Name3      A     Analyst     OD       8  Recommended    0    0    1
3  Name4      C  Supervisor     EO       2     Required    0    0    0
```

I need to use the master roster to get all the names and the other fields in that report. Then, I need to merge that report with a pivoted training report with the `Training` column being broken apart into multiple columns with a count.

My first step was to try to pivot the training report data (not using all the columns) and then merge it with the master roster.

```
pvt = df.pivot_table(index = ['Name','Office','Position'],
                     columns = 'Training',
                     fill_value = 0,
                     aggfunc='count')
```

However, I'm not sure if that is the best way, and that the pivot output doesn't seem to be merge friendly (I could be wrong). In SQL I would just `LEFT JOIN` the training report to the pivoted master roster on the `Name` column.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated on the easiest and best way to accomplish merging those 2 reports to get my final desired outcome. Please let me know if I need to clarify anything further!

----- UPDATE 2 -------

I was able to merge and then pivot the data set, but it's not quite how I want it to look. The merge looks good, and I only bring in the columns I need.

```
result = pd.merge(df4,
                  df[['Name','Training']],
                  on='Name',
                  how='left')
```

I then replace the 'NaN' values in the `Training` column with 'NONE'.
    result.update(result[['Training']].fillna('NONE'))

Merge Output

```
    Name Office    Position Symbol  Status     Required Training
0  Name1      A    Director     OS       1     Required      ADV
1  Name2      B     Manager     BP       3     Required      BEG
2  Name2      B     Manager     BP       3     Required      INT
3  Name3      A     Analyst     OD       8  Recommended      BEG
4  Name4      C  Supervisor     EO       2     Required     NONE
```

However, when I try to pivot the `result` dataframe, I get 'Empty DataFrame' now.

```
cols = ['Name','Office','Position','Symbol','Status','Required']
pvt2 = result.pivot_table(index=cols,
                          columns='Training',
                          fill_value = 0,
                          aggfunc = 'count')
```

-------- FINAL UPDATE ---------
I got it to work! Yay!

```
result = pd.merge(df4,
                  df[['Name','Training']],
                  on='Name',
                  how='left')

result.update(result[['Training']].fillna('NONE'))
cols = ['Name','Office','Position','Symbol','Status','Required']

pvt2 = result.pivot_table(index=cols,                          
                          columns=['Training'],
                          fill_value = 0,
                          aggfunc = len)
```

All I had to do was the change the `aggfunc =`count`to`aggfunc = len`. I hope that ends up helping someone else! If anyone has improvements on this, I'm definitely open to those as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a better way, but this solution works for me! Again, I'm happy to accept feedback or improvements!

```
import pandas as pd
#Create DataFrame for training
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Name1','Name2','Name2','Name3','Name1'],
                   'Office':['A', 'B', 'B', 'A','A'],
                   'Position':['Director','Manager','Manager','Analyst','Director'],
                   'Training Code':['C3','C1-L','C2','C1-B','C3'],
                   'Training':['ADV','BEG','INT','BEG','ADV']
                  })

#Create DataFrame for master roster
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Name1','Name2','Name3','Name4'],
                   'Office':['A', 'B', 'A', 'C'],
                   'Position':['Director','Manager','Analyst','Supervisor'],
                   'Symbol':['OS','BP','OD','EO'],
                   'Status':[1,3,8,2],
                   'Required':['Required','Required','Recommended','Required']})

#Left join the training DataFrame to the master roster DataFrame using the 'Name'
#column as the join key.
result = pd.merge(df4,
                  df[['Name','Training']],
                  on='Name',
                  how='left')

#Substitute any 'NaN' values with 'NONE' so the pivot doesn't drop rows with 'NaN'
result.update(result[['Training']].fillna('NONE'))

#Store all the column headers of the master roster into the 'cols' list
cols = list(roster.columns)

#Pivot the combined 'result' DataFrame using all the columns from
#the master roster DataFrame. The 'Training' column is the column
#that will be broken apart. 'aggfunc = len' does a count of the instances
#of each 'Training' element.
pvt2 = result.pivot_table(index=cols,                          
                          columns=['Training'],
                          fill_value = 0,
                          aggfunc = len)
```